# What is com.mgoogle.android.gms?

Tags: adb, google-play-services, nokia-6

While checking the installed packages in my device through `adb`. I found two packages, `com.google.android.gms` and `com.mgoogle.android.gms`. I know the former is related to Google Play Serivces.

**What is `com.mgoogle.android.gms` and its significance?**

Should I remove it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on quick research of the package name `com.mgoogle.android.gms`, looks like it is **a MicroG package used by YouTube Vanced**.

The installation of this package is [suggested by the official YouTube Vanced for non-root users](https://youtubevanced.com/non-root) if they want to add and login with a Google account.

> ## Download & Install MicroG!
>
> Download and install MicroG for YouTube Vanced in order to be able to connect your google account with YouTube.
> If you don't install MicroG package, "**add account**" button will not work.

The renaming of the package is to prevent any conflicts with existing Google services.